# What influence does ejabberd get from disconnection process

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

- CentOS 7.3.1611
- ejabberd version 17.04

  - Using ElastiCache (Redis) for session store
  - Using Amazon RDS (MySQL) for user database
- Install from official installer

We want the advice about the following situation.

We are caring out the performance test to check if we can connect to 3,000,000 users to XMPP cluster, which we constructed on AWS. There is 10 cluster nodes.
The result is all green, no problem with 3,000,000 users continuous connection.

But, when more than half of the 3,000,000 users try to reconnect, the server which ejabberd is in operation, although there are enough capacity for CPU and Memory, can't start new session.

Is the process of reject and connect disturb the new session?
Also, we want the advice about ejabberd setting and Linux setting, to improve the situation we have right now.

Comment: That sounds like your clients are missing a reconnection backoff strategy, causing all clients are simultaneously attempt to reconnect.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. However, XMPP client we use for performance test supports backoff.